# I have code like this need to apply media query for larger screens

Tags: html, css, media-queries

//need apply media query for larger screens for adjusting like more than 17inch screens.please help me out for this

.vertical-menu1 {

```
     width: 149px;
    height: 165px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    margin-left:605px;
    margin-top:-165px;
}
//container 
.vertical-menu1 a {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #40404c;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family:openSans;
    word-spacing: 0px;
    letter-spacing:0px

}
//on hovering
.vertical-menu1:hover a {
    color:blue;
    font-size:13px;
}

.vertical-menu1:hover a{
    font-weight:bold;
}
//Onhovering 
.vertical-menu1:hover a{
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `@media` property?

Comment: Use [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp) and then use the `in` unit. You can see a list of available [units here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
@media all and (min-width: 17in) {

--- your CSS

}
```

Comment: Am using more than 8 vertical menu with seperate css for each menu  can i apply 1 media query for all of these

Comment: @user8604412 This media query will work for any screen less than 17 inches. You can use it until it displays you well-structured design. However, it is good practice to use different queries for smaller screens.

Answer (score 0):

@media (min-width:1632px){

```
   width: 149px;
    height: 165px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    margin-left:605px;
    margin-top:-165px;
}
//container 
.vertical-menu1 a {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #40404c;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family:openSans;
    word-spacing: 0px;
    letter-spacing:0px

}
//on hovering
.vertical-menu1:hover a {
    color:blue;
    font-size:13px;
}

.vertical-menu1:hover a{
    font-weight:bold;
}
//Onhovering 
.vertical-menu1:hover a{
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
Now a days lage screen resulation start 1440px

@media only screen and (min-width: 1440px) {

   width: 149px;
    height: 165px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    margin-left:605px;
    margin-top:-165px;
}
//container 
.vertical-menu1 a {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #40404c;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family:openSans;
    word-spacing: 0px;
    letter-spacing:0px

}
//on hovering
.vertical-menu1:hover a {
    color:blue;
    font-size:13px;
}

.vertical-menu1:hover a{
    font-weight:bold;
}
//Onhovering 
.vertical-menu1:hover a{
    text-decoration:underline;
}
}
```